# Target display mode mojave

Tags: imac, target-display

I'm trying to use target display mode with a MacBook Pro (Late 2015) as the main computer and an iMac (Late 2013) as the one to switch to TDM. Both devices are running the same version of Mojave (10.14.5). Following the steps outlined [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) when I press command + f2 on the iMac nothing happens. I've tried with a razor keyboard which I use regularly as well with an Apple Bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: You did **all** the troubleshooting steps listed in the support document already?

Comment: I think I did them correctly. Tried logging out and trying the short cut and logging back in. I tried an Apple keyboard instead of my razor one. Not sure if there's any obscurity in the instructions open for common misinterpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Mojave is not supposed to support Target Display Mode. You need High Sierra or **older**.